# How to export test suite from SOAP UI as .bat file?

Tags: testing, soapui

I want to automate SOAP UI test suite running and for that I heard that we can export test suite as a batch program. I searched over internet about it but I didn't get any results on the same. Is it possible to export it into .bat file? If yes then can someone suggest me a way to do it?

Comment: Maybe [this link](http://www.soapui.org/test-automation/running-functional-tests.html) will help get you started.  From a preliminary glance, what you want does seem possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The tests can be automated using soapUI tool. For that one needs to create a *project* which consists one or more *test suite(s)*. Of course, each *test suite* contains one or more *test case(s)*. A *test case* contains one or more *test step(s)* of different types like *soap request*, *rest request*, *http request*, *groovy script*, *jdbc* etc.

SoapUI saves a project as an *xml* file.

From the summary of the question, it appears that there is confusion for you or mixing different things together i.e., **automating** tests and **executing** them, and note that both are different.

Also exporting test suite is not related in this context and doesn't have impact on either automating tests or executing. And not sure, what caused you this confusion.

**Automating Tests**:

Project can be created if you have wsdl / wadl files for soap / rest respectively. More details can be found [here](http://www.soapui.org/soapui-projects/soapui-projects.html). Also [this](http://www.soapui.org/getting-started/functional-testing.html) resource will help to get started with functional testing using **SoapUI**.

**Exporting Test Suite**:

One can export a *test suite* from *SoapUI* project, but that will be of xml file again. This is mainly useful if you want to reuse the existing tests or move it to a different soapui project altogether.

**Executing the Automated Tests**:
Ultimately the goal is to execute the automated tests against the application under test and create the test report.

It is possible to run the tests in the following ways:

1. From SoapUI - the tests suites can be executed from **SoapUI** tool. Find more details from [here](http://www.soapui.org/test-automation/running-from-soapui/functional-tests.html). This method is useful when some wants to try the newly automated tests and make sure all his assertions are going thru after building thier test suite in SoapUI.
2. From Commandline - this method can be approached when some one wants to run the tests as part of *Continuous Integration* or do not wish to invoke SoapUI or run the tests *headlessly* both on windows and unix platforms. For this **SOAPUI_HOME/bin/testrunner.bat or .sh** scripts can be used. For more details see [here](http://www.soapui.org/test-automation/running-from-command-line.html).

Hope this clarifies or helps.

Comment: Thanks for such a detailed response :)

Comment: @Rushikesh, does it answer your query or still looking for some information as it is not accepted answer?